# got error unsupported data type: &[]. this is gorm model + golang/jwt

Tags: postgresql, go, jwt, go-gorm, fibers

### Your Question

Hello
good day

System specs

- go latest
- gofiber
- windows 11
- postgres

Am trying to run AutoMigrate but am having an error, everything was working fine but since last week i get the following error when i run my code.

```
2021/12/30 13:17:56 ←[35mC:/personal/projects/uni-blog/src/database/connect.go:43
←[0m←[31m[error] ←[0munsupported data type: &[]

2021/12/30 13:17:56 ←[35mC:/personal/projects/uni-blog/src/database/connect.go:43
←[0m←[31m[error] ←[0mfailed to parse value &models.Claims{RegisteredClaims:jwt.RegisteredClaims{Issuer:"", Subject:"", Audience:jwt.ClaimStrings(nil), ExpiresAt:<nil>, NotBefore:<nil>, IssuedAt:<nil>, ID:""}, ID:uuid.UUID{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}}, got error unsupported data type: &[]

2021/12/30 13:17:56 ←[35mC:/Users/raliq/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/driver/postgres@v1.1.2/migrator.go:192
←[0m←[31m[error] ←[0munsupported data type: &[]

2021/12/30 13:17:56 ←[35mC:/Users/raliq/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/driver/postgres@v1.1.2/migrator.go:167
←[0m←[31m[error] ←[0munsupported data type: &[]

2021/12/30 13:17:56 ←[35mC:/Users/raliq/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/driver/postgres@v1.1.2/migrator.go:167
←[0m←[31m[error] ←[0mfailed to parse value &models.Claims{RegisteredClaims:jwt.RegisteredClaims{Issuer:"", Subject:"", Audience:jwt.ClaimStrings(nil), ExpiresAt:<nil>, NotBefore:<nil>, IssuedAt:<nil>, ID:""}, ID:uuid.UUID{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}}, got error unsupported data type: &[]

2021/12/30 13:17:56 ←[35mC:/Users/raliq/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/driver/postgres@v1.1.2/migrator.go:167
←[0m←[31m[error] ←[0munsupported data type: &[]
Sorry couldn't migrate'...
Database connection was successful...
```

this is my code and the model where the problem appears, because it migrates the user model then it gets stuck at claims

```
DBConnection

var DB *gorm.DB

func ConnectPg() {
    p := config.Config("DB_PORT")
    port, err := strconv.Atoi(p)
    // port, err := strconv.ParseUint(p, 10, 32)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Sorry db port error: ", err)
    }

    // connection url to DB
    dns := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", config.Config("DB_HOST"), port, config.Config("DB_USER"), config.Config("DB_PASSWORD"), config.Config("DB_NAME"))

    // connect to DB
    var dbErr error
    DB, dbErr = gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dns), &gorm.Config{})

    if dbErr != nil {
        panic("failed to connect to database..")
    }

    fmt.Println("Running the migrations...")

    if migrateErr := DB.AutoMigrate(&models.User{}, &models.Claims{}, &models.Permission{}, &models.Role{}, &models.RolePermission{}, &models.SessionLog{}); migrateErr != nil {
        fmt.Println("Sorry couldn't migrate'...")
    }

    fmt.Println("Database connection was successful...")
}
```

```
Claims model

package models

import (
    "github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/v4"
    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

type Claims struct {
    jwt.RegisteredClaims
    ID uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;default:uuid_generate_v4()"`
}
```

Here is the original code before i migrated to https://github.com/golang-jwt/jwt from https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go. [here is the repo](https://github.com/raliqala/golang-fibre-boilerplate)  i just want to do the same thing as before but its not working.

I changed jwt packages using the golang/jwt v4 now am trying to migrate my code to work with the new change but something is wrong in the models. I want to generate jwt token for access and refresh tokens

please help

Thanks in advance
How i used it to save the audience
[image]

Comment: @https://github.com/longlihale said ```RegisteredClaims.Audience is []string data type, gorm not supported this data type. so you can't use it directly .``` here https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/4972

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scanner/Valuer interface is not implemented for slice types ie []string. So you can use the pq.StringArray type from https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq instead of the []string type in the jwt.RegisteredClaims struct.
You can use a custom struct that have the same fields but with the pq.StringArray type instead of []string.

Comment: Thank you, I did create a custom stuck and created a separate struct that has jwt.RegisteredClaims.

Comment: No problem. It is a pleasure.